# I am on US F-1 visa OPT and I want to apply for Canada PR do I need to give IELTs again?

Tags: canada

I am on F-1 visa OPT and this year my visa is going to get expire. Do I need to give IELTS again for Canada PR? And If I file for canada PR now how long it takes to complete process?

Answer (score 4):

You need to give more details. Presumably you gave IELTS to get F-1 visa and US university admission. That's probably the academic IELTS that you gave. For Canadian Immigration, "General" IELTS is required, academic not accepted. So yes you have to give General IELTS again. You also need to get your highest education evaluated (also known as ECA) before you can submit Express Entry profile (quickest way to get PR if you're not already working in Canada). Based on your EE profile score you may/may not get invited to apply for PR (a.k.a ITA). After you get ITA you need to submit your medical test results, police clearance certificates, employment history reference letters, proof of funds and all the works. From start to end this can take between 8-12 months. You should also look at other immigration tracks such PNP, or apply for studies/work in Canada or move there before getting the PR. CIC's website is very informative, do use it [CIC PR website](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/permanent-residence.html).

Hope this helps.

Edit: here's some more info
https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/permanent-residence/express-entry/applications-received-on-after-january-1-2016-completeness-check.html

https://movnorth.com/process/